# Read and use values from csv file

Tags: csv, ansible, cisco

I'm struggling to find a solution for LAB project I'm working on right now. I'd like to use csv file to populate variables in my playbook when configuring Cisco ACI. I'm using read_csv module and the latest Ansible 2.9

```
Sample CSV:
tenant1;tenant1-vrf;tenant1-app
tenant1;tenant1-vrf2;tenant1-app2
tenant2;;tenant2-vrf2;tenant2-app2
```

*UPDATE* - based on Sai's code I'm not far from reaching the objective. This is the full tasks code.
*UPDATE2* - eventually I went back to the read_csv module. It works nice even for complex things. Hope it helps someone as an example.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Read tenant from CSV file and return a list
      read_csv:
        path: "{{ filename }}"
        delimiter: ;
      register: tenantconfig

    - name: TASK 1 - BUILD tenant
      aci_tenant:
        <<: *aci_login
        validate_certs: no
        use_ssl: yes
        tenant: "{{ item.tenant }}"
        description: "{{ item.tenant }} creation as per {{ filename }} source file"
        state: present
      with_items: "{{ tenantconfig.list }}"

    - name: TASK 2 - BUILD Routing {{ vrf }} for {{ tenant }} on {{ apic_host }}
      aci_vrf:
        <<: *aci_login
        state: present
        validate_certs: no
        use_ssl: yes
        tenant: "{{ item.tenant }}"
        vrf: "{{ item.vrf }}"
        description: "{{ item.vrf }}"
      with_items: "{{ tenantconfig.list }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have changed answer to dynamically process your input file and assign tenant,vrf fields where ever you want to call.

```
tasks:

    - name: split fields
      command: /usr/bin/awk -F';' '!/^#/ && !/^$/ { print $1 }' tenant1.csv
      register: tenants_out

    #- debug:
    #    msg: "{{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=tenant1.csv delimiter=; col=0') }}"
    #  with_items: "{{ tenants_out.stdout_lines }}"

    - name: TASK 1 - BUILD tenant
      aci_tenant:
          state: present
          tenant: "{{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=tenant1.csv delimiter=; col=0') }}"
          vrf: "{{ lookup('csvfile', item + ' file=tenant1.csv delimiter=; col=1') }}"
      with_items: "{{ tenants_out.stdout_lines }}"
```

input file lines are spitted using initial task, and you can direct specify required tenent, vrf values using "with_items"  looping. this is useful if your input file has multiple lines as well.

Comment: Thanks! I like it! (Can't vote unless I have reputation > 15), but it works only to some extent. I played with similar solution before. I'd however need playbook to dynamically get values from csv file. This way I would have to define 'Tenant1' and all profiles either here or with extra-vars in shell. I'd like to have play to read values and use them without my intervention. As in the dict or list style for instance. Can you think of anything like that? Can it be done via set_fact with loops?

Comment: i have changed the answer, in such a way that input file(even with multiple rows) be processed without specifying any column/field name inside the yml file.

Comment: Thanks Sai! Almost there, almost there! I experimented for the past two days, managed to make it more generic. I'm still facing the same problem - how can the script go through lines in CSV, use those cells as variables. I guess this is great alternative to read_csv module (once it's working).